# Graphing $y = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I'm trying to graph the function $y = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$.  I factored the numerator into $(x+2)(x-2)$, and then canceled the common factor (x-2), leaving the function as $y = x + 2$.

Is it acceptable to graph the original function as $y = x + 2$, a straight line with domain and range all real numbers?  Or do you have to restrict the domain as in the original function?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: just leave out what happens to y=x+2 at x=2; and at x=2 we have y=2+2=4 so you would leave out the point (2,4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you divided by $(x-2)$ so you have to assure that $(x-2)\neq0$ so then $x\neq2$ so the Domain is all the real numbers but $2$ ($\mathbb{R}\setminus\{2\}$) and the range is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{4\}$ since $4=x+2$ when $x=2$, the same line but with a gap in $x=2$

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed to know.